# How to produce this list of pure function pairs

Tags: replacement, map, pure-function

I need to produce this

```
{{identifier1 === # || identifier1 === _ &, True &}, {identifier2 === # || identifier2 === _ &, True &}, {_ === # || _ === _ &, True &}}
```

It's basically a list of pairs of {condition, value}. Both condition and value are syntactically both pure functions to allow more flexibility so I can have a master function that can do a lot of things.

The first member of each pair is SameQ-ing the input to an identifier or the Blank (Blanks, as it allows me to have short hands for certain levels). The second member is trivially returning True.

The identifiers come from a list that can vary in content and length and *may* even contain _.

So to generate this, I have:

```
In: {#, True &} & /@ (func[#, x] || func[#, _] & /@ {identifier1, identifier2, _})
```

- this is split into 2 Mapping, so I can illustrate something later

To produce this:

```
{{func[identifier1, x] || func[identifier1, _], True &}, {func[identifier2, x] || func[identifier2, _], True &}, {func[_, x] || func[_, _], True &}}
```

Which I will substitute func with SameQ later on.

Of course, I need to add "&" after every:

```
func[identifier1, x] || func[identifier1, _]
```

So if I were to insert that:

```
In: {# &, True &} & /@ (func[#, x] || func[#, _] & /@ {identifier1, identifier2, _})
```

- this is why I split this into 2 Mapping

I end up with this:

```
{{# &, True &}, {# &, True &}, {# &, True &}}
```

Which is wrong.

Is there a way to "escape" the "&", so "#" expands first, then "&" gets applied. Using `Evaluate[#] &` and `Activate[#] &` does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Map`, I would do:

```
makeRules[pat_] := {pat === # || pat === _ &, True &}
list = {identifier1, identifier2, _};
makeRules /@ list
(* {{identifier1 === #1 || identifier1 === _ &, True &}, {identifier2 === #1 || identifier2 === _ &, True &}, {_ === #1 || _ === _ &, True &}} *)
```

Comment: Of course. It's so simple. Each member of the list gets plugged in `pat` and not `#`. I feel stupid now.

Comment: There doesn't even seem to be a straight forward way of doing this in terms of pure functions. I always had the suspicion that the two aren't completely identical, aside from the notation.

Comment: Well, I did it that way first, (`makeRules = Function[{pat}, {pat === # || pat === _ &, True &}]`), but I decided it was more straightforward just to define it the way I did. Note that when you are trying to "nest" pure `Function`s, one of the `Function`s has to have named variables; otherwise, the `Function`s don't know which `Slot` belongs with which `Function`.

Comment: Just to be clear for other readers, by "pure Functions", I actually meant the *inline* anonymous pure function way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion:

```
With[{identifiers = {identifier1, identifier2, _}},
 Transpose[{
   Table[With[{id = id}, id === # || id === _ &], {id, identifiers}]
   ,
   Table[True &, {Length[identifiers]}]
   }]
 ]
```

Since all the first elements, and all the second elements, of each pair are related, it made more sense to me to generate them separately and use `Transpose` to make the pairs. The `With[{id = id}, ...]` is there to inject the actual identifiers into the pure functions, avoiding the `HoldAll` attribute of `Function`.

Comment: I guess the `Transpose` is still lacking in my toolkit. I've always thought that with `Map` and all, the language lacks natural-looking mechanisms/constructs to "weave" distinct lists together.

Comment: In my experience `Transpose` is also very fast, especially with numerical stuff :)